# highcharts tooltip alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to render my charts

The problem is with the xaxis label

For Stacked_Column the label appears in the center

But for Column the label is not aligned in the center

Please suggsest how to fix it.

Comment: Please replicate your issue as live demo, i.e jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'm confused - is the question about tooltips or axis labels?

Comment: For the [Basic Column](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic), the label is aligned in the center of the vertical x-axis lines. Which exact chart type are you using?